# Submit to cron schedule from other cron jobs

Tags: cron

How do you submit a job for the cron scheduler from another (cron)job?

I have several cron jobs running with different time schedule. But I would like to submit a bunch of jobs whenever som logic is true in the program.

It works fine by adding a record to the 'cron_schedule' table with SQL, but maybe there was some kind of Factory object build-in Magento?